# How can I use Quickhull to sum two geometries with Three.js?

Tags: three.js

I'm puzzled with the Quickhull extension. How can I find a convex hull of two objects? I need them hulled after translation, so perhaps I need to translate the actual vertices rather than simply altering the position? Having trouble finding any documentation of this extension, so thanks for any light shed by those who know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to merge the meshes together and then get the ConvexHull of that meshes.geometry.

```
var box = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
var sphere = new THREE.SphereGeometry(.65, 32, 32);
sphere.position.x = 4;
var singleGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();

var boxMesh = new THREE.Mesh(box);
var sphereMesh = new THREE.Mesh(sphere);

boxMesh.updateMatrix(); // as needed
singleGeometry.merge(boxMesh.geometry, boxMesh.matrix);

sphereMesh.updateMatrix(); // as needed
singleGeometry.merge(sphereMesh.geometry, sphereMesh.matrix);

var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0xFF0000});
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(singleGeometry, material);

if(mesh.geometry.type==='BufferGeometry')mesh.geometry = new THREE.Geometry().fromBufferGeometry(mesh.geometry);
mesh.geometry = new THREE.ConvexGeometry(mesh.geometry.vertices);
scene.add(mesh);
```

Comment: Since Geometry has been depriciated (since r125) this is no longer correct answer

Comment: This was asked in 2018. Now you would use BufferGeometry instead of Geometry and it should work.

Comment: Also the term is 'deprecated'.. depreciated is slightly different meaning. :)